# Dual nature of matter and electromagnetic radiations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

I haven't completely understood the dual nature of matter and electromagnetic radiation.
If all matter has wave nature and and all waves have particle nature then how will one distinguish between particles and waves? If there is no distinction between a particle and a wave then what is a matter wave...shouldn't all waves be called matter waves?
(I am new to this concept so the question may be silly)

Comment: Hi Osheen. The wave particle duality is a fascinating subject and can really only be understood by learning quantum field theory. However I strongly recommend you to read the question I've linked as I think it will give you the general idea.

Comment: Wave particle duality is a failed concept. One can work with waves alone, which is pretty much what we do these days in quantum field theory. What is not so known is that the "mystery" had been solved in 1929, already, when Mott explained the emergence of alpha particle tracks as the result of a weak interaction between the quantum field and matter. All subsequent attempts to make it into something of importance are basically just lack of knowledge of the authors of those attempts.

Comment: [My own take on the subject is here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134849/are-double-slit-patterns-really-due-to-wave-like-interference/134850#134850)

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are getting at. I will take my best shot.

Particles are subatomic and waves of particles are classic physics. Quantum physics and classic physics do not agree. 
Einstein saw the power in matter while Tesla saw the power in empty space that was just proven with the Higgs Boson and Quantum Entanglement. Both are right or wrong, pending on which physics you are going by.

This is the way I understand it. Please correct me if I am wrong.